# FB App Invites with Xamarin

Tags: ios, facebook, xamarin

I am looking at how to implement a Facebook invite dialog and noticed that Facebook now offers a new [FB App Invite](https://developers.facebook.com/products/sharing/app-invites) product.
Is there a way to use the new App Invite product with Xamarin iOS?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the implemention of app invites

> *You need to create Native implementaion for appinvites*

Just create one interface called IFacebookService

Define Method defination as shown in example

```
public interface IFacebookservice{
  InviteFriends (string appLinkURL, string previewImageURL);
}
```

and do that implementation on platform side as shown in below

**IOS**  `FacebookService.CS`

```
public void InviteFriends (string appLinkURL, string previewImageURL)
{
            var fromController = UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.RootViewController;
            var content = new AppInviteContent {
                AppLinkURL = new NSUrl (appLinkURL),
                PreviewImageURL = new NSUrl (previewImageURL)
            };
            AppInviteDialog.Show (fromController, content, null);
}
```

**Android** `FacebookService.Cs`

```
  public void InviteFriends(string appLinkURL, string previewImageURL)
    {
        if (AppInviteDialog.CanShow())
        {
            var activity = Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Context as Activity;
           var content =new AppInviteContent.Builder().SetApplinkUrl(appLinkURL).SetPreviewImageUrl(previewImageURL).Build() as AppInviteContent;
            AppInviteDialog.Show(activity, content);
        }
    }
```

**Usage in Xamarin Forms**

```
  var facebookservice=Dependency.Get<IFacebookservice>()
    button.click+=delegate{facebookservice.InviteFriends("appurl","previewimageurl")}
```

Comment: I followed the above implentation and its work fine with read droid device and iOS Simulator. But on real iPhone it doesn't show Invite dialog. No error, no exception, nothing. any though on this?

Comment: Do you guys get this to show the native dialog or the web dialog? We are using the above implementation but still get the web browser version

Comment: @https://stackoverflow.com/users/2086778/softsan Try to implement the error handler from my post below

Answer (score 2):

It's currently not supported by the Xamarin FB SDK. The invite feature is available from version 4.0, where the transformed version of FB SDK was done on version 3.6.

So you basically have two options:

1) Ask Xamarin dev team to update the FB sdk to version 4.0, you can check it [here](https://xamarin.uservoice.com/forums/145075-xamarin-component-ideas)

2) Since it will probably won't be ready soon, you can take the FB iOS **native** sdk, and generate a xamarin library by yourself.
More details can be found in this  [link](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/binding_objective-c/Walkthrough_Binding_objective-c_library/)

If you do decide to go on  option #2, it would be great if you would share your transformed sdk.

Answer (score 1):

The answer from [Jagadeesh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2517418/jagadeesh-govindaraj) is completely correct. Also consider implementing a result handler when returning from the Facebook multi-friend-selector. If at least one friend was invited, the Facebook API feedback will show it. For iOS the result can be 'canceled by the user' or completed

- {completionGesture = cancel; didComplete = 1;}
- {didComplete = 1;}

For Android nothing when 'canceled by the user', but if completed:

- Bundle[{didComplete=1}]

**Android**

```
        AppInviteDialog AppInv = new AppInviteDialog(activity);
        AppInv.RegisterCallback(callbackManager, invitecallback);
        AppInv.Show(content);
        var invitecallback = new FacebookCallback<AppInviteDialog.Result>()
        {
            HandleSuccess = Result =>
            {
                if ((string)Result.Data == "Bundle[{didComplete=1}]")
                {
                    textbox.Text = "Friend Invited";
                }
            },
            HandleCancel = () =>
            {
                textbox.Text = "Cancelled";
            },
            HandleError = Error =>
            {
                textbox.Text = "Error" + Error.Message;
            }
        };
```

**iOS**

```
    var dlgt = new MyAppInviteDialogDelegate();
    var dialog = AppInviteDialog.Show(fromController, content, dlgt);
    public class MyAppInviteDialogDelegate : AppInviteDialogDelegate
    {

        public override void DidComplete(AppInviteDialog appInviteDialog, NSDictionary results)
        {
            textbox.Text = "Friend Invited";
            if (results.Description.Contains("cancel")) 
            {
                textbox.Text = "Cancelled";
            }
        }

        public override void DidFail(AppInviteDialog appInviteDialog, NSError error)
        {
            textbox.Text = "Error" + error.Description;
        }
    }
```