# Facebook App Invite for Xamarin

Tags: c#, facebook, windows-phone-8, xamarin, google-app-invites

I am developing an application using Xamarin with traditional approach for all 3 platforms : Android, iOS and Windows Phone 8

For all 3 platform we would like to achieve the functionality of App Invite from Facebook.

But we could find the feasibility for only Android and iOS Native application support.

How could I achieve this?

I have tried with the following approaches

- Need to convert Facebook SDK of iOS and Android to support for Xamarin by creating wrapper of C#. But that is again not going to support for windows phone
- For .Net library tried with : http://facebooksdk.net/docs/ But again we could not find App Invite Feature through it.

What should be the solution.

Requirement : I require this feature because I would like to invite my friends to join my application.

Answer (score 0):

A bit old, but maybe can help you someone -
Take a look at this thread:

[FB App Invites with Xamarin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29283775/fb-app-invites-with-xamarin)

Answer (score -1):

App Invites are support only for Android and iOS. You will not find any library beside the original iOS and Android sdks with this feature. You have to bind and implement this feature separated in each platform (Android and iOS, Windows phone is not supported).

Comment: Axis pingpay application is able to get the facebook friends !! How is that possible ?

Comment: Did you ever find out how they do that?